# Игнорируется лимит на размер загружаемых файлов

Tags: php, nginx, cgi

Настраиваю php-сервер для обработки прайсов. Работает Apache в связке с Nginx. Режим работы php - **CGI**. В файле **php.ini**, среди прочего, указаны такие настройки:

```
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 300M
```

В файле **nginx.conf** указано

```
http {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 128m;
}
```

Однако максимальный размер загружаемых файлов всё равно не может превышать 2Мб. При загрузке файлов, размер которых превышает 2Мб, в глобальной переменной `$_FILES` содержится ошибка: `$_FILES['Price']['error'] == 1`

Вроде всё сделал правильно, но всё равно не работает, почему-то, как мне надо. В какую сторону мне вообще смотреть? Какие мануалы курить?

**UPD:** Сервер управляется ПУ ISPmanager. PHP v7 подключен в виде альтернативной версии для **CGI**, так как из коробки у ISPmanager нет PHP v7, только v5.33. Поэтому пришлось использовать CGI, так как альтернативные версии только в этом режиме подключаются, а играться с обновлением стандартного пыха и его привязкой к панели не было времени - сервер чисто промежуточный для формирования прайсов.

Comment: что в логах пишет? это отбивает nginx или apache?

Comment: покажите вывод `phpinfo` -- что вообще пишет в настройках этих переменных? Я как-то ошибался в конфиге апача и ставил толи букву М не в том регистре, толи ещё что-то -- поэтому переменная не устанавливалась. А у вас подобное на nginx, надо проверить что там по документации означает `m` малая

Comment: Изредка встречаются сайты где запущен как fcgi - не ваш случай? Приходится ставить ещё `FcgidMaxRequestLen` _в дополнение_ к переменным, которые вы цитировали

Comment: @AK в логах пусто. Ошибку выбивает не апач или nginx, а хранится она в глобальной переменной php, отвечающей за загрузку файлов. Ошибка, мол файла нет. Других ошибок нет. Файлы < 2Мб грузятся норм. fcgi вроде не запущен. Как проверить?

Comment: Хотя нет,  `m` малая работает в конфигах nginx: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056124/nginx-client-max-body-size-has-no-effect

Comment: @AK вывод `phpinfo();` выдаёт стандартные значения: `upload_max_filesize = 100M` и `post_max_size = 300M`. Забыл сказать, кое-что. Сейчас допишу в вопрос...

Comment: @AK добавил **UPD** в вопрос с дополнительной информацией.

Comment: Опечатку в заголовке даже править жалко.

Comment: @D-side Владимирский апач, ветер северный. Работает с Nginx, зла немеряно. Режим работы - CGI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Давая дополнительную информацию по своему вопросу, случайно догадался о решении проблемы.

Так как я использую альтернативную версию PHP в режиме **CGI**, то конфиги для этой версии должны быть отдельными, по идее. И это оказалось именно так. Я их нашёл - они лежат непосредственно в `/var/www/php-bin-isp-php70/`. Там же лежит и **php.ini** конкретно для этой версии. А я менял `/etc/php.ini`, который отвечает за стандартную версию PHP в режиме апача.

В общем, я отредактировал конфиг `/var/www/php-bin-isp-php70/php.ini` и теперь всё работает.

Спасибо всем, кто участвовал в решении моей проблемы. :)

Comment: Хорошо, что все хорошо заканчивается.